# can I make ringtone in preferences

Tags: java, android, preference, ringtone

How can I make ringtone activity (that always appear in setting) so the user can choose her ringtone from system ringTones I googled it but I didn't find complete tutorial, I am really confused, please give me tutorial or some codes.

Also, if I want the user to choose the special ringtone to Notification in my application should i use Shared preference or preference?

I already did the Menu:

```
      // Menu Code Part#2
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.about:
  startActivity(new Intent(this, About.class));
    return true;
    case R.id.help:
  startActivity(new Intent(this, Help.class));
    return true;
    case R.id.setting:
   startActivity(new Intent(this, Setting.class));
        return true;
    default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Full code:

**res/xml/preferences.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <PreferenceCategory
                android:title="Second Category">

        <RingtonePreference
                android:name="Ringtone Preference"
                android:summary="Select a ringtone"
                android:title="Ringtones"
                android:key="ringtonePref" />

</PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

**Preferences.class**

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences); 

 }
}
```

**Your code go here:**

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.about:
   // startActivity(new Intent(this, About.class));
    return true;
    case R.id.help:
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Help.class));
    return true;
    case R.id.setting:
    Intent settingsActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                                                Preferences.class);
                                startActivity(settingsActivity);


        return true;
    default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

To read these preferences from code, we should create a `getPrefs()` method, which we can call in the `onStart()` method. When we call it in the `onStart()` method instead of `onCreate()`, we can be sure that the preferences load when we have set them and returned to our main activity,
The `getPrefs()` method could look like this:

```
String ringtonePreference;
// Get the xml/preferences.xml preferences
                SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
 ringtonePreference = prefs.getString("ringtonePref",
                                "DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI");
```

**androidmanifest.xml**

```
<activity
        android:name=".Preferences"
        android:label="@string/set_preferences">
</activity>
```

Comment: the first code in mainfist ? and the second code i should put it in newActivity and i should call the newActivity in the menu? right? also the second code, is it complete code to reingtone?or do i need another code?

Comment: @user1257040:first code in your preferneces.xml file and second code where you want to access selected Ringtone.

Comment: is it complete code? i mean there is no need to another code?

Comment: hi friend,your problem solved or not bez this code perfectly working on my side..

Comment: it'ok friend,put this code in activity or service where you want to play user selected ringtone

Comment: can i ask you how to put the disable application notification in Preference? please

Comment: sure,tell me more what you want to do?

Comment: my application has Alarm Notification and SMS and MMS notification, i want  to give the user the option to Disable all these Notification and put this option in preference, so i create CheckBox but what is the code and where should i put it ? Thank you

Comment: ok then use CheckBoxPreference and add this code in preferencs.xmle file    <CheckBoxPreference android:key="show_notification"  
        android:title="Disable Notification" android:summary="Disable all  Notification SMS,MMS" />

Comment: i can not run it right now because i should complete my application code, but i will ask you: this little code will really disable the Notification?

Comment: can i ask you about how can i put Tell friend code? i wanna to add it in XML like the Ring tune. i have already tell friend in java but i do not know how can i put tell friend(java code) and ring tune(XML code) in the same List

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110926/disable-notificaion-in-sharedpreference-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `SharedPreferences` to store the URI of the ringtone the user selected. You can let the user select a ringtone using this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Ringtone");
if (mRingtoneUri != null) { 
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, Uri.parse(mRingtoneUri));
} else {
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, (Uri) null);
}
startActivityForResult(intent, RINGTONE_REQUEST);
```

The above code will prompt the user to select a ringtone from the system. When they select one, you will need to handle the `Activity` result:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == RINGTONE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        if (uri == null)
            editor.putString(RINGTONE, null);
        else
            editor.putString(RINGTONE, uri.toString());
        editor.commit();
        if (uri == null)
            mRingtoneUri = null;
        else
            mRingtoneUri = uri.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

This code will save the URI of the ringtone to `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: your code will let the user pick a ringtone from the system, rigth?

Comment: Yes. Try it yourself and see.

Comment: In the `Activity` where you would like to have the user select a ringtone.

Comment: Thank you, but can you please told me where should i put each code? in Activity? or in preferenceActivity? Thank you