# volume in PreferenceActivity doesn't save if changed

Tags: android, volume, preferenceactivity, ringtone

how can i change the volume from PreferenceActivity? i have this xml:

```
<RingtonePreference
        android:name="Ringtone Preference"
        android:summary="Select a ringtone"
        android:title="Ringtones"
        android:key="ringtonePref" />
<VolumePreference
    android:name="Volume Preference"
    android:summary="Ringtone Volume"
    android:title="Ringtone Volume"
    android:key="ringVolPref"/>

</PreferenceCategory>
```

and the Class extends PreferenceActivity:

```
public class SettingTest extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.ringtone);
```

I don't know how to change the volume (If i run the app, it display the Volume SeekBar, but won't save the changes)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    super.onStart();
}
```

Remove **android:name** from xml,
preference xml should look like
[this](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/res/xml/preferences.html).

Comment: I dont think i understand, could you please be more specific? Where shoul i put this in the code above? Thanks a lot

Comment: see the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650516/can-i-make-ringtone-in-preferences/9650577#9650577) there is a good example, addPreferencesFromResource must be from xml folder

Answer (score 0):

`[VolumePreference][1]` is in fact hidden in the API, so you probably shouldn't be using it.
When I use this code, the value is actually stored; it remebers the position on the `SeekBar`. 
Naturally the value is not saved in the application's preferences file, because the settings should be applied to the system, and not to the app...

But, even though it seems to remember the position correctly, the volume is not actually affected at all. You might want to take a look at how the settings app does it:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.4_r1.2/com/android/settings/RingerVolumePreference.java#56